# Check if variable contains text or numbers

Tags: php, variables, preg-match

Im creating a search function. The users are only allowed to use a-z A-Z and 0-9. How do i check if $var only contains text or numbers, and not special characters ?

I have tried something like this:

```
if (!preg_match('/[^a-z]/i', $search) {
$error = "error...";
}
```

If anyone have a smarter solution, please let me know. It could also be something checking for special characters.

Comment: Looks OK -- why not `/[^A-Za-z0-9]/`, though?

Comment: Are you not allowing spaces in there?

Comment: Spaces should be allowed

Comment: Just add a space before the ] of any of @brain's answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much there. Just add numbers 0-9 to your regular expression, like this:

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $search)) 
{
    $error = "Error...";
}
```

The `/i` flag tells the expression to ignore case, so `A-Z` is not needed inside the letter list.

In your original code, you were looking for anything that *wasn't* a letter or number, while also checking to see if `preg_match()` *hadn't* matched anything - you created a double negative. The code above executes the `if()` if anything that *isn't* a letter or number *is* found. Full credit to @brain in the comments.

---

To allow other characters, simply add them to the characters inside the braces:

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9 \.]/i', $search)) 
{
    $error = "Error...";
}
```

This example allows spaces and `.` (dots).

Comment: Only problem with this one is that, in this case, preg_match should return >0 if there are bad characters in the string. So get rid of the "!". Also, need one more ")". :-)

Comment: Hmm, it gives me the $error everytime no matter what i search for

Comment: Ah okay, it works now. If i want to add some special characters that i choose, how do i do that ?

Comment: And i want to allow spaces too :-)

Comment: @JamWaffles Thank you very much! Still one problem though, i cant get special characters to work: `/[^a-z0-9 \æøå&]/i`  i want to allow æøå and & too. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure how PHP handles these characters in regex, but try escaping each one separately like: `\æ\ø\å`.

Comment: @JamWaffles hmm it does not work. I'll search for it on Google.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $search)) {
    // error
}
```

Comment: [..]+ means the good characters must be present at least once. The ^ and $ means it will match a whole line, and not just anywhere within the line. Basically.